# Cannot add javascript eventListener to recently created element

Tags: javascript, web, event-handling

I use Javascript to created 625 `<div class="box"><div>` then I want to add event listener for each box. The boxes is successfully created but the listener is not working. Here my full code, I really appreciate for all of your response. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Number AI | Machine Learning Technologhy</title>
    <style>
        .box-container{
            display: grid;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
        }
        .box{
            width:10px;
            height:10px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initiateBox(){
            for (let i = 0; i < 625; i++) {
                let box = document.createElement("DIV");
                box.classList.add("box");
                document.querySelector('.box-container').appendChild(box);
            }
        };
        window.onload = initiateBox;
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>Number AI</h2>
        <div class="box-container"></div>
        
        <script>
            document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(box =>{
                box.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
                    box.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've to attach the events in the load handler too. Currently `querySelectorAll` doesn't find any elements, as they're not created yet. Notice that with event delegation, instead of creating 625 functions and events, you could attach a single listener to `.box-container` element, and change the background color of `event.target`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have several options here. But the simplest one *(Not the efficient one)* is to add the event listener on box creation like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Number AI | Machine Learning Technologhy</title>
  <style>
    .box-container {
      display: grid;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initiateBox() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 625; i++) {
        let box = document.createElement("DIV");
        box.classList.add("box");
        box.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
          box.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
        });
        document.querySelector('.box-container').appendChild(box);
      }
    };
    window.onload = initiateBox;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Number AI</h2>
  <div class="box-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

But in any case, if you looking for an efficient way to do this as @mplungjan pointed out in comments it's better to use [delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) approach like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Number AI | Machine Learning Technologhy</title>
  <style>
    .box-container {
      display: grid;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initiateBox() {
      const boxContainer = document.querySelector('.box-container');
      for (let i = 0; i < 625; i++) {
        let box = document.createElement("DIV");
        box.classList.add("box");
        boxContainer.appendChild(box);
      }

      boxContainer.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        if (target.classList.contains('box'))
          target.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
      });
    };
    window.onload = initiateBox;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Number AI</h2>
  <div class="box-container"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is highly inefficient with 625 eventlisteners

Comment: There are many benefits - here are just 2:  1. smaller memory footprint - you now have 625 listeners 2. you can add more boxes later and they will still work without having to add more listeners

Comment: @mplungjan I totally agree with it but as I said 625 event listener do not cause any memory leak or whatever. But its wiser and may be beneficial to add it to their parent.

Comment: It seems generally advised to delegate and personally prefer it due to the elegance of it. Also you can in the same delegation look at different child elements

Comment: @mplungjan That's true. But as I said this is one of many approaches and simplest one to add them on creation. 

Comment: As you can se in my answer it is not difficult to add them delegated

Comment: Ah, so you just added my code to yours instead of just voting my answer up?

Comment: @mplungjan Well, I think voting up or down is optional. I wrote the code myself but I honour you by mentioning your name there.

Answer (score 1):

Several things

1. use addEventListeners on load and on mouseover
2. delegate so you can cerate the boxes at any time after the container exists
3. Perhaps a CSS hover is the actual way to do this ?

Anyway, here is the delegation script

```js
function initiateBox() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.box-container');
  for (let i = 0; i < 625; i++) {
    let box = document.createElement("div");
    box.classList.add("box");
    container.appendChild(box);
  }

  container.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("box")) tgt.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  });
};
window.addEventListener("load",initiateBox)
```

```css
.box-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto;
}

.box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<title>Number AI | Machine Learning Technologhy</title>

<h2>Number AI</h2>
<div class="box-container">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the second script is run before the box elements are appended to the document, thus not finding any boxes. You could add the eventListener to the initiateBox function you created, like so:

```
function initiateBox(){
        for (let i = 0; i < 625; i++) {
            let box = document.createElement("DIV");
            box.classList.add("box");
            box.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
                box.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
            });
            document.querySelector('.box-container').appendChild(box);
        }
    };
    window.onload = initiateBox;
```

If the background color is actually the property you are going to change on the mouseOver, I would suggest doing that with a CSS hover though.

Comment: It is highly inefficient with 625 eventlisteners